# How to keep a list in the different View in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swift3, swiftui, swiftui-list

In  my SwiftUI app, I have tab view at the bottom of the screen.
in other to keep the code clean, i want to have each Tab in a separate view/class. In one tab i have list. For some reasons I cannot move the list into a separate view. This is my initial code:
import SwiftUI

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var rooms : [Rooms] = []
    @State var selectedView = 1
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView() {
                List(rooms) { rooms in
                    Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                    HStack {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(rooms.name)
                            .font(.headline)
                        Text("members")
                            .font(.body)
                        }
                    }
                }.tabItem { Image(systemName: "waveform.path.ecg") }.tag(1)


                ExtractedView().tabItem { Text("Tab Label 2") }.tag(2)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This is how I tried to make the a separate view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var rooms : [Rooms] = []
    @State var selectedView = 1
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView() {
                ExtractedView1(rooms: rooms).tabItem { Image(systemName: "waveform.path.ecg") }.tag(1)


                ExtractedView2().tabItem { Text("Tab Label 2") }.tag(2)
            }
        }

    }
}

struct ExtractedView1: View {
    let rooms : Rooms
    var body: some View {
        List(rooms) { rooms in
            Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(rooms.name)
                        .font(.headline)
                    Text("members")
                        .font(.body)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea why this is wrong? I get the following errors:

Error 1: [Rooms] is not convertible to Rooms

Error 2: Generic parameter 'SelectionValue' could not be inferred

If this is suggested, I would even move it to a different swift file.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is some confusion between an array of Rooms: `[Room]` and a single `Room` object datatype. Just make sure you make your view with the List to accept an array of Rooms: `[Room]` so that it can iterate over them

```swift
struct Room: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var rooms : [Room] = []
    @State var selectedView = 1
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView() {
                ExtractedView1(rooms: rooms).tabItem { Image(systemName: "waveform.path.ecg") }.tag(1)


                ExtractedView2().tabItem { Text("Tab Label 2") }.tag(2)
            }
        }

    }
}

struct ExtractedView1: View {
    let rooms : [Room]
    var body: some View {
        List(rooms) { room in
            Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(room.name)
                        .font(.headline)
                    Text("members")
                        .font(.body)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ExtractedView2: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("ExtractedView2")
    }
}
```